# Make m(illi)g(ram) come before g(ram)

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I need to perform an advanced type of sorting of some pharmaceutical products.

One of the columns I sort on is strength. I want to order on ascending strength, and for example, in one result set, we may find products with strengths of 500 mg and 1 g. But right now, the 500 mg always come after 1 g. How do I make it understand that `mg` is smaller than `g`? I'm not allowed to change `1 g` to `1000 mg` as it is part of the official product description.

Right now I'm using `ORDER BY``` `strength` ```+ 0`.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Obviously, use junk data if the real stuff is sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by the presence of `mg` first:

```
ORDER BY strength rlike 'mg' desc, strength + 0
```

in mysql true is `1` and false is `0`, and `rlike` returns true if the string matches (ie *contains*) `mg`, so this will sort all milligram strengths before other strengths.

Comment: I solved it using `INSTR`, but your solution is basically the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this extensible and more usable you need to create a second table, say UNITS:

```
UNIT | VALUE
mg   | 0.001
g    | 1
Kg   | 1000
```

Then, create a second column in your table, UNIT - with a foreign key into UNITS, and remove this from your string, turning your value into a number. You can concatenate them later for extraction.

You can then join on your "reference" table and order easily:

```
select concat(t.strength, t.unit)
  from your_table t
  join units u
    on t.unit = u.unit
 order by u.value, t.strength
```

If you don't do something like this then you'll have to change your ORDER BY clause whenever you change the table, which will invariably be forgotten.